# Calculating database cell value

Tags: mariadb

My issue is to calculate the division of one column and another column and to return it to new column in the database.

So each one of the cell in one column should be divided with cell that is next to her in other column.

How can I do that?

[image: picture]

So in this picture every element of column "izmerenavrednost" and every element of column "ciljanavrednost" should give element in column "ocenavrednosti"

column"izmerenavrednost"/ column"ciljanavrednost"=column"ocenavrednost"

Comment: What have to done so far?

Comment: IS it to substract izmerenavrednost-ciljanavrednost" or division ?

Comment: sorry i will change not subtrack division ..my mind is currently in a mess

Comment: @Pera There you go. Its MariaDB server, you have posted under SQL. Use IFNULL in place of ISNULL.

Comment: @BHouse Still the same message. thank you very much for staying with me, but i do not want to be boring. you tried your best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would help

```
    Update table 
    set   ocenavrednost = ifnull(izmerenavrednost ,0.00)/ ifnull( ciljanavrednost ),0.00)
```

Comment: You can end up trying to set `ocenavrednost = 0/0`

Comment: It could eliminate null values in division, of one is null and other one has a value . it should not return null Isnt it ?

Comment: @B House it doesn't work when i put Update bsc 
set   ocenavrednost = isnull(izmerenavrednost,0)/ isnull(ciljanavrednost,0) and it works when i put Update bsc 
set   ocenavrednost = isnull(izmerenavrednost)/ isnull(ciljanavrednost) but only divide when they are both null and when they have both numbers nothing happends

Comment: I assume data types are not int in both, what data types are they  varchar ?

Comment: Run this and check                                                                               
   select  izmerenavrednost from table where isnumeric(izmerenavrednost) = 1

Comment: both values are double

Comment: Your new edit didn;t do anything, but thanks, i will keep looking for

Comment: @Pera are you getting error or is it  returning null values

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'decimal(18,2)),'0.00')/ isnull(cast( ciljanavrednost as decimal(18,2)),'0.00')' at line 2

Comment: @B House and now i read one of your previous questions, it shoudn't return null

Comment: @BHouse now when i typed correctly i got this message : #1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ifnull'

Comment: Just  some minor mistakes after checking everything but you helped me a lot..thanks :)

Comment: I hope you didn't give up, we all learn from trial and error. Use Coalesce instead of Isnull

Comment: No, ofcourse, just i had  a tough period last nigth, couldn't realise  where to start. now i see light at the end of the long street .and i will implement it.

Comment: @Pera That's nice attitude. Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this is what you are after?

```
UPDATE table
SET ocenavrednost = izmerenavrednost / ciljanavrednost
```

If you wanted to subtract instead, then it would be this query:

```
UPDATE table
SET ocenavrednost = izmerenavrednost - ciljanavrednost
```

Comment: Yes,but for every cell in both columns

Comment: It absolutely needs some null checks as it looks like those columns can be NULL.